# Using Map Feature service from ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-service

I use ArcGIS Online for my work and we have a third party company who wants to use our data and they requested that we give them a feature service link for part of the integration but I do not see that option when I go to create a map. We do not have ArcGIS Server and from what I have found online we need ArcGIS Server to create this feature service.

Is that correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your contractor is wanting a REST link that you can provide through ArcGIS Online. Almost everything you publish on ArcGIS Online has some kind REST service, but there are a couple caveats.

If you have publish a layer to ArcGIS Online it will say  *Feature Layer (hosted)*

[image]

If you got the items details page at the bottom right column will be a REST end point service link.

[image]

For Feature Layers it is a Feature Service; <s>if you publish an entire map, it will be a Map Service link.  Do note that ArcGIS Online Map Service links do not support Query operations, so that might change your use cases.</s>

[image]

Just change your sharing options to ensure that the contractor can see the layer, if it is a layer with editing enabled, create a VIEW of the layer and share that instead. If it is something that they need to edit, do realize that the edits will only exist on ArcGIS Online and not your local file geodatabase (FGDB).

---

I think I might be going crazy unless ESRI changed something, which is VERY likely. I am 99% sure, you used to be able to create service links for host Maps. But it looks like you need to turn the Map into a hosted Tile Service now for a Map Service link.

Comment: FGDB? Im sorry I dont know what that means

Comment: @cucv Sorry, File Geodatabase, commonly the way to store data on your disk, usually appears as a folder with the suffix `.gdb`. But ArcGIS treats the folder as a database. Just know that if the contractor needs/given edit access the edits will live there until you download them or you use Enterprise to share.

Answer (score 0):

Is the third party seeking information long term and you want to manage the feature? Or is this a "one off" request that you can treat the feature like a file? There are several options that don't require Server.
If you're looking to share a feature service you may be able to create a collaboration with the third party, or if it is a hosted feature layer you might be able to supply them with the feature service link (bottom right of the feature details page in your Content). There are some other options, as well.

Comment: It will be long term,  I looked at my content page and I don't have that link on my online maps. am I missing something to create it for them?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don’t ask questions within this area which is reserved for answers. You will be able to seek clarifications using the comment anywhere privilege once you have a reputation of 50.